# Using Motion class for lumia 520

Tags: windows-phone-8, accelerometer, gyroscope, motion-detection

I am trying to get the trajectory of the mobile using the sensor data. I tried logging accelerometer data but noticed that it includes gravitational acceleration also. The developer website says that the Motion class can give cleaner data since it combines various sensors. Is it possible to use Motion class on Lumia 520, even though it has no gyroscope?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Motion` class cannot be used on Lumia 520, not because of lack of gyroscope, but the lack of magnetometer (i.e. compass).

`Motion` class requires accelerometer and compass data, and it uses gyroscope data if available too, for better results.

Since there is no magnetometer in the Lumia 520, `Motion` class won't work on it. `Motion.IsSupported` will be false.